# SSRS sort icon not showing up in header but showing up in column values

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, header, icons

[image: My Result]

I am very new to SSRS. Infact this is my 2nd report.So in SSRS, I went to Interactive Sorting and checked the "Enable interactive sort on this text box". Chose the first radio button "Detail rows".For sort by I chose "ColumnName" and clicked ok. I ended up with a sort icon on every value .The data here may seem duplicate but it is correct. I have additional 6 columns apart from this "Product" column. I repeated the sort action for all columns same way, the only difference being the different "Sort by" column. I get the icon on all columns in all rows. I want it on the header only.
 Apart from that I get this warning 6 times :[rsIneffectiveSortExpressionScope] The text box ‘ColumnName’ is defined at the scope “Details”, which is identical to the scope used as SortExpressionScope. This interactive sort has no effect at runtime, since it sorts only the particular instance itself. 
What is that i am doing wrong ?and what should i do to correct it?

Comment: Enable interactive sorting on "Product" Textbox instead of adding it in details textbox.

Comment: @Konza. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: @Konza. Got it. I have to do it for the Header as against the column value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rt click on the textbox with the Column Name, click on

> Interactive Sorting

then Check

> Enable Interactive Sorting on this textbox

and then select the appropriate group you want to sort.

**AFTER EDIT**

if you dont have any groups yet, just select `Details Row`. If you have/create any group, then you need to select the radio button `Group`.

The `sort by` will actually have the column you want to sort with.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and I no longer see the icon. But it is not sortable. Its like static,fixed grid.I hover over it and nothing happens.I also did this for all columns.SHould i do that? I am doing this because I want all my columns to be sortable.I dont have any group yet. I chose "Groups" radio button and dropdown gave me "Details" as one of the options. I chose that. I did not mention anything in the "Sort by:" section. Anything wrong/missing?

Comment: Well it did not bring up the column value. I put it there. I repeat I am doing this for all 6 columns with their respective columns.Now i get an error on preview "An unexpected error occured in Report Processing.Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Thats what I exactly did. Checkbox,detail rows, column name. 3 things. Doing that brought up the icon in every column,every value like the image i posted. should i be doing this for all the columns in my table?

Comment: You Should do it for that textbox which has the column name, try this [link](http://www.sqlcircuit.com/2012/11/ssrs-how-to-implement-interactive-sort.html) as well

Comment: @BhupeshC.Got it. What i was doing wrong was that, I was doing the sort thing for column value as against the "Header".  It makes sense now.Like I mentioned, very new to SSRS. Thanks